# Routing with large URL query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building a simple `GET` form.

After the user has searched for something, he gets the expected result. The values are separated into different pages. Here's where my problem lies.

If I want to route to a different page, but keep all of the URL parameters, I have to do something like this.

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("MyRoute", new {
    page = ...,
    search = ...,
    dateFrom = ...,
    dateTo = ...,
    orderBy = ...,
    ...
})">
```

You get the idea. I have to copy & paste this bit of code all over the place, and it's really messing up the code. The whole point was only to change the `page` attribute...

Is there a way to get the current route with all parameters, and then change a single parameter individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `ViewContext.RouteData.Values`:

```
@{
    var currentRouteValues = ViewContext.RouteData.Values;
    currentRouteValues["page"] = "new page";
}
@Url.RouteUrl(currentRouteValues);
```

**Update.** In MVC 5 `RouteData` is available via `Url.RequestContext.RouteData`.

Comment: `ViewContext.RouteData.Values` is not available in **MVC 5**. Is there an alternative method/class?

Comment: @NSAddict, did not know this. However seems there is another way to get route data. see update

Comment: Is it correct that you can't access a class called `Url` in code (I'm writing a helper method right now)? I suppose `Url` is just pseudo and not a real class. There is a class called `RequestContext` with a `RouteData` property, but no Url class. How can I get the instance of `RequestContext` from code?

Comment: @NSAddict, Url here is not a class - it is a property of ViewPage, see [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewpage.url%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I just saw that you can also get the `RouteData` from the `RouteTable` class.

Comment: @NSAddict, then you better off using `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData`

Comment: I just noticed that normal queries get lost... --> `/example/url?thisData=isLost`

Comment: I used `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString` to copy the values manually in the helper. Shutting up now :P